# Chaining .then functions in ES6 fetch call

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, fetch-api

I have been looking for a way to figure this problem out and apologize if my searching skills are not up to par.

**My Issue:** I am fetching an API and I want to know when all of the data has been fully loaded. Reading through the docs, it appears that I can chain .then statements with fetch and I thought that would work. But, it appears that they all seem to fire at the same time without waiting for the previous .then to finish.

**Here's my code:**

```
fetch(myUrl, {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
       'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',            
     },
    credentials: 'include',         
    body: data
    })                                
        .then(fetchStatus)  
        .then(json)  
        .then(function(msg){                                    
            showSearchResults();
            setTimeout(function(){ console.log("Next then should fire after this"); }, 4000);                                   
        })
        .then(function(){
            return console.log("The 2nd is firing!");                                  
        });

function fetchStatus(response) {  
    if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {  
        return Promise.resolve(response)  
    } else {  
        return Promise.reject(new Error(response.statusText))  
    }  
}

function json(response) {  
    return response.json()  
}
```

This is great if it is asynchronous, but these events need to be synchronous due to the fact that I am trying to work with content that is created by the previous call, showSearchResults();

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: If you're using ES6 don't forget about the `msg => { ... }` function notation. It can save a lot of verbosity and avoids the `var self = this` dance.

Comment: try wrapping `showSearchResults` in Promise.all and wait for that to resolve

Comment: It's unclear what the problem is here. You have a single `fetch` call, and each handler in that chain will run only after the previous one runs. What's the problem, exactly? (Also: Shouldn't you be providing some kind of argument to `showSearchResults`?)

Comment: You will need to promisfy `showSearchResults` and return that promise within that `then()` callback

Comment: You need to wrap `setTimeout` into the promise: `new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => { ...; resolve(); }, 4000))`.

Comment: Side note: `fetchStatus` can just `return response` in the "good" case, no need for `Promise.resolve(response);` `then` creates a promise, and resolves it with what you return.

Comment: Thanks for all of your help. I ended up having to add a promise and the code dillonius01 gave is giving me the desired results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chaining a `.then` does not guarantee that code will execute sequentially unless you have returned a promise from the previous `.then` call. In your example, if you want the second `console.log` to execute after `showSearchResults`, you should `return showSearchResults()` and chain your `.then` off of that (this only works if `showSearchResults` returns a promise; if it does not, you will want to wrap it in one similar to how you have for `fetchStatus`).

Similarly, if you want to chain a `.then` off of a `setTimeout`, you could write something like:

```
fetch(url, { method: 'post', etc... })
   .then(fetchStatus)
   .then(json)
   .then(function(msg){
      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
         setTimeout(function() {
            console.log("Next then fires after promise resolves");
            resolve();
         }, 4000)
       })
    })
    .then(function(){
       console.log("Second is firing")
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(error)) // always remember to catch errors!
```

Comment: This works exactly as I was hoping for it to work. I tried this method before posting, but I didn't have the "new" keyword in my Promise and struggled with that for a while. Thank you for your help!