# How to properly await Nuxt calls with async/await or .then

Tags: vue.js, axios, fetch, nuxt.js

Im trying to fetch an API using chaining with `.then` but I don't figure it out I try like:

```js
async fetch() {
  let path = this.$nuxt.context.route.path

  this.response = await axios.get(
   `/api${path}`,
   
  {
    headers: {
      'X-AUTH-TOKEN': process.env.SECURE_TOKEN, 
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  }
).then((res) => {
  this.results = res.data.content.slice(0,40);
    return results();
  })
  .then((res) => {
  this.results2 = res.data.content.slice(20,40);
    return results2();
  })
},
```

For my API data load: when results is finish /results2 start to load, for using it with `$fetchState.pending`

What will be the best way of doing it? I'm trying to adapt the answer [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46529214/chaining-then-functions-in-es6-fetch-call) but no success so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of code should be working fine

```html
<script>
export default {
  async fetch() {
    this.response = await axios
      .get(`/api${this.$route.path}`, { // faster than this.$nuxt.context.route.path
        headers: {
          'X-AUTH-TOKEN': process.env.SECURE_TOKEN,
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
      })
      .then((res) => { // ❌ this is useless because you're already using await above
        const results = res.data.content.slice(0, 40)
        return results()
      })
      .then((res) => { // ❌ this is useless because `slice` is NOT async
        const results2 = res.data.content.slice(20, 40)
        return results2()
      })
  },
}
</script>
```

Otherwise, I can also recommend a better approach overall, using `async/await` and not mixing it with `.then` at all, like this

```html
<script>
export default {
  async fetch() {
    const response = await axios.get(
      `/api${this.$route.path}`,

      {
        headers: {
          'X-AUTH-TOKEN': process.env.SECURE_TOKEN,
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
      }
    )
    const results = response.data.content.slice(0, 40)
    const results2 = results.data.content.slice(20, 40)
  },
}
</script>
```

PS: note that some things are not async, hence do not need `await` (or `.then` at all).

---

It can even be shorten to the following

```html
<script>
export default {
  async fetch() {
    const response = await this.$axios.$get( //  using the shortcut $get
      `/api${this.$route.path}`,

      {
        headers: {
          'X-AUTH-TOKEN': process.env.SECURE_TOKEN,
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
      }
    )
    const results = response.content.slice(0, 40) //  no need for `.data` here
    const results2 = results.content.slice(20, 40) //  same here
  },
}
</script>
```

Thanks to the shortcuts available with the [axios module](https://axios.nuxtjs.org/usage#-shortcuts) that you should be using anyway.

---

As of why you should use `async/await`, it's just more lisible and available everywhere already (IE is dead). Here is some more info about the whole `async/await` thing: https://javascript.info/async-await

Far prettier than [this kind of syntax](https://blog.avenuecode.com/callback-hell-promises-and-async/await) (also named `callback hell`)

[image]

Comment: Thank you Kissu ..thats great im trying the shorten version but i get : Error in fetch(): TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'content') do i missing something maybe

Comment: @J.O the `.then` version is wrong overall because you're using both async/await and then. I recommend trying the 3rd approach or even the 2.

Comment: Yes im trying the 3rd approach now thanks again Kissu :)