# How do I retrieve data from my MYSQL database as an array?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

I have a backend API using a MySQL database, I am trying to retrieve data from my database and use the data to plot the latitude and longitude on a map using the google maps API. I am using the Gmaps API with Nuxt JS.
I have tried to do this with the code below but I have encountered an error which says

> "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'coordinates')"

[image]

I am trying to retrieve my data with the below code

```js
async function getData(){
  const {data} = await this.$axios.$get('http://localhost:8000/api/parkingPlace');
  console.log(data)
  return {data}
}
```

and then pass this data into my Gmaps.

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      currentLocation: {},
      circleOptions: {},
      parkingPlaces: getData(),
```

Which I can then use to retrieve my values of latitude and longitude and plot these as pins onto my map.

```html
<template>
  <div class="min-h-screen relative max-6/6" >
    <GMap class="absolute inset-0 h-100% bg-blue-400"
      ref="gMap"
      language="en"
      :cluster="{options: {styles: clusterStyle}}"
      :center="{lat:parkingPlaces[0].coordinates.lat, lng: parkingPlaces[0].coordinates.lng}"
      :options="{fullscreenControl: false, styles: mapStyle}"
      :zoom="5">

      <GMapMarker
        v-for="location in parkingPlaces"
        :key="location.id"
        :position="{lat: location.coordinates.lat, lng: location.coordinates.lng}"
        :options="{icon: location.free_spots > 0 ? pins.spacefree : pins.spacenotfree}"
        @click="currentLocation = location"
      >
        <GMapInfoWindow :options="{maxWidth: 200}">
          <code>
            lat: {{ location.coordinates.lat }},
            lng: {{ location.coordinates.lng }}
          </code>
        </GMapInfoWindow>
      </GMapMarker>
      <GMapCircle :options="circleOptions"/>
    </GMap>
  </div>
</template>
```

My whole `index.vue` class is below where I am trying to do this.

```html
<template>
  <div class="min-h-screen relative max-6/6" >
    <GMap class="absolute inset-0 h-100% bg-blue-400"
      ref="gMap"
      language="en"
      :cluster="{options: {styles: clusterStyle}}"
      :center="{lat:parkingPlaces[0].coordinates.lat, lng: parkingPlaces[0].coordinates.lng}"
      :options="{fullscreenControl: false, styles: mapStyle}"
      :zoom="5">

      <GMapMarker
        v-for="location in parkingPlaces"
        :key="location.id"
        :position="{lat: location.coordinates.lat, lng: location.coordinates.lng}"
        :options="{icon: location.free_spots > 0 ? pins.spacefree : pins.spacenotfree}"
        @click="currentLocation = location"
      >
        <GMapInfoWindow :options="{maxWidth: 200}">
          <code>
            lat: {{ location.coordinates.lat }},
            lng: {{ location.coordinates.lng }}
          </code>
        </GMapInfoWindow>
      </GMapMarker>
      <GMapCircle :options="circleOptions"/>
    </GMap>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
async function getData(){
  const {data} = await this.$axios.$get('http://localhost:8000/api/parkingPlace');
  console.log(data)
  return {data}

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      currentLocation: {},
      circleOptions: {},

      parkingPlaces: getData(),

      // parkingPlaces: [
      //   {
      //     "id": 1,
      //     "name": "Chandler Larson",
      //     "post": "37757",
      //     "coordinates": {
      //       "lng": -51.84,
      //       "lat": -60.02
      //     },
      //     "total_spots": 0,
      //     "free_spots": 0
      //   }
      // ],

      pins: {
        spacefree: "/parkingicongreen3.png",
        spacenotfree: "/parkingiconred3.png",
      },
      mapStyle: [],
      clusterStyle: [
        {
          url: "https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m1.png",
          width: 56,
          height: 56,
          textColor: "#fff"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I have tried to use Axios to retrieve data from my database and pass this into my google maps to display points on the map.

I am expecting points to appear on my map where data from my database gives the `lat` and `lng`.

EDIT 1:

I have now edited some of my code to reflect the changes as suggested by @kissu.

```
<template v-if="parkingPlaces.length > 0">
  <div class="min-h-screen relative max-6/6" >
    <GMap class="absolute inset-0 h-100% bg-blue-400"
      ref="gMap"
      language="en"
      :cluster="{options: {styles: clusterStyle}}"
      :center="{lat:this.parkingPlaces[0].coordinates.lat, lng: this.parkingPlaces[0].coordinates.lng}"
      :options="{fullscreenControl: false, styles: mapStyle}"
      :zoom="5">

      <GMapMarker
        v-for="location in parkingPlaces"
        :key="location.id"
        :position="{lat: location.coordinates.lat, lng: location.coordinates.lng}"
        :options="{icon: location.free_spots > 0 ? pins.spacefree : pins.spacenotfree}"
        @click="currentLocation = location"
      >
        <GMapInfoWindow :options="{maxWidth: 200}">
          <code>
            lat: {{ location.coordinates.lat }},
            lng: {{ location.coordinates.lng }}
          </code>
        </GMapInfoWindow>
      </GMapMarker>
      <GMapCircle :options="circleOptions"/>
    </GMap>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

// async function getData(){
//   const {data} = await this.$axios.$get('http://localhost:8000/api/parkingPlace');
//   console.log(data)
//   return {data}
// }

export default {

  data() {
    return {
      currentLocation: {},
      circleOptions: {},
      parkingPlaces: [],


      // parkingPlaces: [
      //   {
      //     "id": 1,
      //     "name": "Chandler Larson",
      //     "post": "37757",
      //     "coordinates": {
      //       "lng": -51.84,
      //       "lat": -60.02
      //     },
      //     "total_spots": 0,
      //     "free_spots": 0
      //   }
      // ],

      pins: {
        spacefree: "/parkingicongreen3.png",
        spacenotfree: "/parkingiconred3.png",
      },
      mapStyle: [],
      clusterStyle: [
        {
          url: "https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m1.png",
          width: 56,
          height: 56,
          textColor: "#fff"
        }
      ]
    }
  },

  async fetch(){
    this.parkingPlaces = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/parkingPlace').then(res => res.json())
    console.log(this.parkingPlaces)
  }

}

</script>
```

Result of my `console.log(this.parkingPlaces)`

[image]

EDIT 2

[image]

Answer (score 1):

#### EDIT

You have an object at the end in your `this.parkingPlaces` as shown by your `console.log`.
You need the following to access the actual data (as an iterable array).

```js
async fetch() {
  const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/parkingPlace')
  const json = await response.json()
  this.parkingPlaces = json.data
  console.log(this.parkingPlaces)
}
```

PS: I also recommend that you use [`this.$axios.$get` shortcuts](https://axios.nuxtjs.org/usage#-shortcuts) as [showcased here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74329715/8816585).

---

What is `getData`? Put that function into a `methods` in your `export default {` rather.
Then, use `asyncData()` or `fetch()` hook to fetch the data properly in a Nuxt way, you can call `this.getData` inside of any of them.

Apply a conditional in your `template` so that you have a fallback in your template (only needed for `fetch()`'s lifecycle hook). `asyncData` is indeed render-blocking.
It can be `v-if="parkingPlaces.length"`, no need for more.
But [don't stack both](https://vuejs.org/style-guide/rules-essential.html#avoid-v-if-with-v-for) at the same time. ESlint can warn you about that.

Here is [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67490633/8816585), there we're using `$fetchState.pending` to wait until we have our data before iterating over the array. Without that conditional, the template will iterate on something empty and throw the error that you do have.

Indeed, the `template` section is not clever enough to understand that the data may be async. Hence it is run into a `sync` approach. Using a conditional is enough to make it aware of the possibility of something being empty (because not fully async fetched).

---

More info on how to fetch data in Nuxt available here: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/data-fetching#the-fetch-hook

Comment: Hi @kissu, getData is my function name which is supposed to return some data from my database.

Comment: @cookiemonster300 why is it outside of the `export default` block was my main question. Put it inside, especially if you are not planning to re-use it anyway.

Comment: I have adapted my code as mentioned above but I still seem to get the same error ```async fetch(){
    this.parkingPlaces = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/parkingPlace').then(res => res.json())
  }```

Comment: @cookiemonster300 please edit your whole question to reflect your changes. And don't forget the conditional rendering with the `v-if`.

Comment: @cookiemonster300 updated back.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249926/discussion-between-cookiemonster300-and-kissu).